# Reading multiple depended files in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I am working on a program in python and having a bit of trouble. What my program is supposed to do is read a line from a file, parse it, and write a section of that line to a string. It then should search though another file for that string, and when it finds it print that line.
It should then move down to the next line of the first file and repeat the process until all lines from the first file have been read.

My code to do this is the following:

```
def readermain():
    """called if constant file exists"""

    for line in portslist: #reads printer port list and parses name and port address 
        marker = line.split()
        printername=marker[0]
        address=marker[1]

        for lines in constantfile:
            if address in lines: #if the desired address is in the line
                lineholder=lines.split()
                print (lineholder)
                oldonline=lineholder[4]
                oldutc=lineholder[5]
                status=lineholder[2]
                address=lineholder[1]
```

The problem is, the first `for line in portslist` does not seem to move on to the next line. It prints out the same line over and over again. Both `portslist` and `constantfile` and lists declared else where in the program using `constantfile=open("constantfile.dat").readlines()` etc. I am new to python and cannot seem to figure out what is going on here. Any help or suggestions are more than welcome.

The program itself is pretty long, I tired to sum up the problem area, but I will post it below. It is a work in progress so there are other things wrong that I am aware of, and yes, it is not the best example of readability, sry. Still suggestions are great.

```
"""Program to pull down list of printers and ping each to see if it is online. 
Will track printers over time, if printer has been offline for over a year it will be listed in a delete file.
This program is designed to run on windows and requires python to be installed. """

import win32com.client, os, time, datetime
from datetime import datetime




computername="(name goes here)"
currentdate=datetime.now()
currentdateutc= (time.mktime(currentdate.timetuple()))

def getPorts(computername):
    """Gets printer name and port name"""

    portslist= open("printerports.txt","w")

    objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
    objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(computername,"root\cimv2") 
    colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer") 
    for objItem in colItems:
        list= objItem.Name + " " + objItem.PortName+"\n"
        portslist.write(list)

    portslist.close()

def pingone(address):
    """Pings address and returns 0 if it is online"""
    pingreturn=os.system("ping -n 1 " + address)
    return (pingreturn)

def pingfive(address):
    """Pings as address five times"""
    pingreturn=os.system("ping -n 5 " + address)
    return (pingreturn)

def online(printername, address, currentdate):
    return str((printername +" at port "+ address+" is online on "+ str(currentdate)+"\n"))

def offline(printername, address, currentdate):
    return str((printername +" at port "+address+" is offline on "+ str(currentdate)+"\n"))

def constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc):
    return str((printername+" "+address+" "+str(0)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(currentdateutc)+"\n"))

def constantoffline(printername, address, currentdate, oldonline, oldutc):
    return str((printername+" "+address+" "+str(1)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(oldonline)+" "+str(oldutc)+"\n"))

def removal(printername, address, oldonline):
    return str((printername+" with queue "+address+" has been offline since "+str(oldonline)+"\n"))

def constantfilecheck():
    """Checks for constant file"""
    if os.path.isfile("constantfile.dat")==True:  #checks if a constant file exists. if not one is made
        return True

    else:
        return False

def readermain(portslist, constantfile, counter, oncounter, offcounter):
    """called if constant file exists"""

    for line in portslist: #reads printer port list and parses name and port address 
        print(line)
        marker = line.split()
        printername=marker[0]
        address=marker[1]

        for lines in constantfile:
            print(lines)
            if address in lines: #if the desired address is in the line
                lineholder=lines.split()
                print (lineholder)
                oldonline=lineholder[4]
                oldutc=lineholder[5]
                status=lineholder[2]
                address=lineholder[1]
                #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                print ("Address found in constant file")

                if pingone(address)==0:
                    newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
                    onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currentdate))
                    oncounter += 1
                    counter += 1

                else:
                    if pingfive(address)==0:
                        newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
                        onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currentdate))
                        oncounter += 1
                        counter += 1

                    else:
                        newconstantfile.write(constantoffline(printername, address, currentdate, oldonline, oldutc))
                        offlinefile.write(offline(printername, address, currentdate))
                        offcounter += 1
                        counter += 1
                        if status == 0 and (currentdateutc-oldutc)>=31556926:
                            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            print("printer older than year")
                            deletefile=open("removefile.txt", "a")
                            deletefile.write(removal(printername, address, oldonline))
                            deletefile.close()
            else:
                #not in constant file
                #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                print("not in constant file")
                if pingone(address)==0:
                    newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
                    onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currentdate))
                    oncounter += 1
                    counter += 1

                else:
                    if pingfive(address)==0:
                        newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
                        onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currrentdate))
                        oncounter += 1
                        counter += 1

                    else:
                        newconstantfile.write(printername+" "+address+" "+str(1)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(oldonline)+" "+str(currentdateutc)+"\n")
                        offlinefile.write(offline(printername, address, currentdate))
                        offcounter += 1
                        counter += 1

def readersecondary(oncounter, offcounter, counter):
    """called if no constant file exists already"""

    for line in portslist: #reads printer port list and parses name and port address 

        marker = line.split()
        printername=marker[0]
        address=marker[1]

        if pingone(address)==0:
            newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
            onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currentdate))
            oncounter += 1
            counter += 1

        else:
            if pingfive(address)==0:
                newconstantfile.write(constantonline(printername, address, currentdate, currentdateutc))
                onlinefile.write(online(printername, address, currrentdate))
                oncounter += 1
                counter += 1

            else:
                newconstantfile.write(printername+" "+address+" "+str(1)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(currentdate)+" "+str(currentdateutc)+"\n")
                offlinefile.write(offline(printername, address, currentdate))
                offcounter += 1
                counter += 1
    return counter, oncounter, offcounter
def rename():
    """Deleates old constant file and renames newconstantfile to constantfile"""
    if constantfilecheck() is True:
        os.system("del constantfile.dat")

    os.system("ren newconstantfile.dat constantfile.dat")
    os.system("del printerports.txt")

#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
#END OF FUNCTIONS
#_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________


oncounter=0
offcounter=0
counter=0

print ("Getting ports from server\n")   
getPorts(computername)

portslist=open("printerports.txt", "r").readlines()
newconstantfile=open("newconstantfile.dat", "w")
onlinefile=open("onlinefile.txt", "w")
offlinefile=open("offlinefile.txt", "w")

print ("checking for constant file")
if constantfilecheck() == True:
    constantfile=open("constantfile.dat").readlines()
    print("calling reader main")
    readermain(portslist, constantfile, counter, oncounter, offcounter)
    constantfile.close()
elif constantfilecheck() == False:
    print("calling reader secondary")
    readersecondary(oncounter, offcounter, counter)

offlinefile.write("\nTotal Printers Scanned: "+str(counter))
offlinefile.write("\nPrinters online: "+str(oncounter))
offlinefile.write("\nPrinters offline: "+str(offcounter))
onlinefile.write("\nTotal Printers Scanned: "+str(counter))
onlinefile.write("\nPrinters online: "+str(oncounter))
onlinefile.write("\nPrinters offline: "+str(offcounter))

portslist.close()
newconstantfile.close()
onlinefile.close()
offlinefile.close()

rename() #calls rename function
```

I know I shouldn't be using os.system, but this was supposed to be a quick and dirty little project for work. The program is meant to keep track of a large number of printers (in the thousands) online status over a long period of time (years). It does this by pinging a list of printers pulled from a print server, and recording dates, online status, and port names, in the constantfile.

Here is a line from the portslist file:
`artp002 10.40.80.18` formatted "name port"

And here is a example of the constant file:
`artp002 10.40.80.18 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0'
with the format "name port date_last_checked last_online_date time_in_utc

And here is an output from when the program is run:

```
Getting ports from server

checking for constant file
calling reader main
artp002 10.40.80.18

artp002 10.40.80.18 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0

['artp002', '10.40.80.18', '0', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '1346347954.0']
Address found in constant file

Pinging 10.40.80.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.40.80.18: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 10.40.80.18:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 6ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 6ms
artp002 10.40.80.18 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0

['artp002', '10.40.80.18', '0', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '1346347954.0']
Address found in constant file

Pinging 10.40.80.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.40.80.18: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 10.40.80.18:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 6ms, Maximum = 6ms, Average = 6ms
artp002 10.40.80.18 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0

['artp002', '10.40.80.18', '0', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '1346347954.0']
Address found in constant file

Pinging 10.40.80.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.40.80.18: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=61
```

Here is some of the output with the `print (line)` after `for line in portslist:`

```
Getting ports from server

checking for constant file
calling reader main
artp002 10.40.80.18

artp002 10.40.80.18 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0

['artp002', '10.40.80.18', '0', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '2012-08-30', '13:32:34.787000', '1346347954.0']
Address found in constant file

Pinging 10.40.80.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.40.80.18: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 10.40.80.18:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 8ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 8ms
artp011 artp011.printers.xxxxxx.edu 0 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 2012-08-30 13:32:34.787000 1346347954.0

not in constant file

Pinging 10.40.80.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.40.80.18: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=61
```

Comment: This depends on where and how `portslist` and `constantfile` are defined and called. Is there a way you can include that code? (BTW, it would be a good idea to pass those two parameters to the function, like `readermain(portslist, constantfile)` rather than have them be global).

Comment: try doing `print line` right after `for line in portslist:`, and `rint lines` right after `for lines in constantfile:`, that can help you figure out what's going on

Answer (score 0):

When you read all the lines of a file, you must rewind the cursor back to the start using `file_object.seek(0)`. Otherwise, further attempts to read lines return `None`. I corrected your code below, see the very last line:

```
def readermain():
    """called if constant file exists"""

    for line in portslist: #reads printer port list and parses name and port address 
        marker = line.split()
        printername=marker[0]
        address=marker[1]

        for lines in constantfile:
            if address in lines: #if the desired address is in the line
                lineholder=lines.split()
                print (lineholder)
                oldonline=lineholder[4]
                oldutc=lineholder[5]
                status=lineholder[2]
                address=lineholder[1]

        constantfile.seek(0) # rewinds the file
```

Comment: `constantfile` seems to be a list, not a `file`, according to the question

Comment: @Claudiu, it might be. It's not clear from the question. If you are right, it's a great example of poor object name choice. I simply assumed that he did the opening and closing of files elsewhere.

Comment: hah indeed. but he does say `constantfile=open("constantfile.dat").readlines()` in the question. that bug would make sense, though.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. It must be a list then. Strange, because if it was a file the bug I described would make sense...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the naming convention. It was originally a file.

Answer (score 0):

Make your code easier to read and test, then you'll find the problem easier. Speficically:

- Name variables for what they hold:

  - `for port_info in portlines:`
  - `for printer_details in consntantfile:`
- Separate words in variable names with underscores:

  - `printer_name`, not `printername`.
  - `old_utc`, not `old_utc`.
- Instead of relying on global variables like `portlines` and `constantfile`, pass them as arguments to this function. Then you'll be able to call this function with a small set of data, and debug the problem by hand.
- Provided us with contents of two files, and the output of your program.

Comment: I have provided the full code, examples from both files, and an output. Please have a look and see what you can find.

Comment: You need to be sure that `constantfile` has distinct lines. Does it? What will you see if you write `print constantfile` right before `for lines in constantfile:`? Your code appears fine, so please confirm that the inputs are valid.

Comment: I added some more output. The file has distinct lines, in the function `readersecondary` the `portslist` file is read correctly(line by line). The constant file is setup the same way, and already has a `print line` under it, the output for that is in the first output example.